# Android - multiple webViews with multiple webViewClient : shouldOverrideUrlLoading not called on new webViewClient

Tags: android, webview, multiple-instances, webviewclient

I have an android activity with a fragment dedicated for multiple webviews.

I've implemented what i could about multiple webview methods including

```
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) { 
    // source code here ... 
}
```

For the first webview, shouldOverrideUrlLoading(..) gets called OK.

But as I follow some links and create a new webview, 
setup excatly the same as the first one,
assign new webViewClient and new webChromeClient.

The new webViewClient override functions such as onPageStart(..), onPageFinished(..) will call ok,

but only shouldOverrideUrlLoading() does not get called on the new webview despite it has a totally new webViewClient instance.

I've checked the instance ids of both webViewClient and confirmed that they have different instance ids for each webviews (which is good because it means both webviews have actually different instances of webViewClients)

I have no clue why the new instance of webViewClient will not trigger shouldOverrideUrlLoading() function.

Can anybody help me? :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had a similiar situation.
In your web-client, you can implement the following:

```
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
       WebResourceResponse response = super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
    return response;
}
```

and you can set a breakpoint in the middle to see what's going on.
**My problem was that the request method was POST**, and that did not trigger the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, so **make sure that your request method is GET.**

Comment: Thank you i'll check it out!